# Is using a language limitation to simplify an answer cheating?

Tags: discussion, code-challenge

This question is mostly in regards to [This challenge and the comments](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/194683/calculate-the-internal-angles-of-a-regular-polygon-with-n-sides)

My planned answer for a microcontroller language could do one of two things: make a general process to handle any input but will very definitely output incorrectly for inputs above a certain threshhold (max output is 255 / FF).

Or it could "abuse" the fact that for this question I may only need to support a few possible inputs as the rest will fail - making my code less general but shorter, however this does feel like cheating so wish to clarify if this would be allowed first

Comment: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/45941